# How do I get a list of components from a control?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a component derived from `ErrorProvider`.  I have a `BaseForm` and `BaseUserControl` that each have this custom `ErrorProvider` added in the designer.  I have many nested `BaseUserControls` on a `BaseForm` and on other `BaseUserControls`, and I need to find all of the custom `ErrorProviders` on the nested controls from a top level form or user control in order to access special functionality.

How can I walk through all nested controls and find all the `ErrorProvider` components?  For example:

```
List<ErrorProviderEx> customProviders = GetErrorProviders(myUserControl);
```

The closest I've come is a recursive method that loops through `myUserControl.Controls` and inspects each control's `Control.Container.Components` collection, but that leads to some crazy logic, having to look backward in the recursive call at a control's `Container`.  I'm also trying to avoid using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components of a `Form` or `UserControl` aren't exposed in any collection. You'll have to do this yourself.

First, declare an interface that your `UserControl`s will implement:

```
public interface IComponentList
{
  List<Component> Components
  {
    get;
  }
}
```

Next, in your `UserControl`, add the components to a list in the constructor, and expose this list through the interface property `Components`:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, IComponentList
{
  private List<Component> _components = new List<Component>();

  public UserControl1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    _components.Add(errorProvider1);
  }

  List<Component> IComponentList.Components
  {
    get
    {
      return _components;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the following function should get you a list of `ErrorProvider`s on all `UserControl`s that implement the `IComponentList` interface:

```
public List<ErrorProvider> GetErrorProviders(Control myControl)
{
  List<ErrorProvider> foundErrorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>();
  GetErrorProviders(myControl, foundErrorProviders);
  return foundErrorProviders;
}

protected void GetErrorProviders(Control myControl, List<ErrorProvider> foundErrorProviders)
{
  if (foundErrorProviders == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("foundErrorProviders");
  }
  if (myControl is IComponentList)
  {
    foreach (Component component in ((IComponentList) myControl).Components)
    {
      if (component is ErrorProvider)
      {
        foundErrorProviders.Add((ErrorProvider) component);
      }
    }
  }
  foreach (Control control in myControl.Controls)
  {
    GetErrorProviders(control, foundErrorProviders);
  }
}
```

Call the method like this:

```
GetErrorProviders(myUserControl);
```

**Note:** The Windows Forms Designer places all components in a variable called `components` in the `.designer.cs` file. You could choose to just add all components in the `components` collection to the `_components` list, but I read the following [here](http://www.vbinfozine.com/a_disposable_comp.shtml):

> [...] I've realized that the
>   `components` member is actually used
>   **only when a component having a
>   specific constructor** is placed onto a
>   Form. [...] If
>   the component exposes a constructor
>   with the specific signature Public Sub
>   New(ByVal c As IContainer), then the
>   `components` Form member is instantiated
>   and passed to the component's
>   constructor

...which is why I'm hesitating in utilizing the `components` collection, since it will not necessarily contain all your components. It *will* work with the `ErrorProvider`, though.

You might want to take a look at [this forum post](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic42685.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I started to go that route but didn't want the coupling.  It looks like it's probably the best way to go, though.  I also knew about the private components collection in the .Desinger.cs file, but didn't want to reflect into a private field for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement in that I needed to find and reference ErrorProvider instances in UserControls derived from a custom base user control class. I used reflection in the base class to do this. The code is shown below (in VB.NET).

```
    Protected ErrorProvidersList As List(Of ErrorProvider) = New List(Of ErrorProvider)()

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    '' Get a collection of error providers that will allow us to check for errors
    For Each fi As FieldInfo In Me.[GetType]().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        Dim obj As Object = fi.GetValue(Me)
        If TypeOf obj Is ErrorProvider Then
            ErrorProvidersList.Add(obj)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```